# Getting "?" character in front of certain strings when using SSIS to convert view nvarchar to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, data-conversion

I am using SSIS to convert and move data from a SQL Server view made up of various tables with lots of joins. All data is originally from Sap B1 pulled into my required tables made up of `nvarchar` data then converted to `varchar` data as that is what my destination needs.

I regularly pull data directly from SAP into SQL Server and this has not been a problem until recently (I pull this and more data regularly and no other data is giving me this trouble only the following so far and would like to get to the bottom of it so I can understand why it is happening).

SSIS Flow is literally like this (AllQuotes_View) > (Data Convertion) converting from nvarchar to "String [DT_STR]" 100 length, codepage (1252 ANSI - Latin I) for the column in question" > (AllQuotes_Table)

Destination table create code

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AllQuotes_Table]
(
    [quote_no] [int] NULL,
    [quote_prepared_for] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [quote_customer] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [quote_ref] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [quote_prepared_by] [varchar](155) NULL,
    [quote_date] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [quote_currency] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [quote_currency_letters] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [quote_total] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [product_qty] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
    [product_sku] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [product_description] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [product_stock] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [product_unit] [numeric](21, 6) NULL,
    [product_total] [numeric](38, 7) NULL,
    [LineNum] [int] NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [U_EmailCont1] [varchar](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This has worked before for over a year successfully in the past but lately, some of the data in column product_sku have a "?" added in front of the expected string.  E.G. when moving a row containing product_sku '‎5HB12A' from the (AllQuotes_View) through the data conversion shown above to the (AllQuotes_Table) the data when doing a select on the table comes out as '?5HB12A'

To note when viewing the data in the view in the designer or using a select statement from the view in Management studio before converting and moving to my destination table it doesn't have the leading "?".

Can anyone shed any light on this, I have tried googling but it is a hard subject to put into short search terms.

I can just run the code below on the destination table to remove the "?" character from the start of the string.

```sql
UPDATE AllQuotes_Table 
SET product_sku = RIGHT(product_sku, LEN(product_sku) - 1) 
WHERE product_sku LIKE '?%';
```

However, this is a quick fix and is not getting to the root of the problem and I wish to find out why this is actually happening.

I have run a select on all columns to see if the same "?" is being added to any other columns but it is not.

This has run successfully over 1000's quotes and product_sku's is the only column that seems to be affected and the only data that this has happened on so far are the following strings

```
?RDR-80582AKU
?4ZB97A#B19
?5HB12A
?EG-2000 IT
?EG-2000-01
```

Can anyone suggest anything to try to find out why this is suddenly happening or a fix to my problem? without the replacement code as this seems like a bodge.

Thank you for any suggestions for a fix or a guide on anywhere to start looking.

Comment: If the source data has Unicode data (let’s say, a poop emoji), how do you expect SQL Server to store that in a varchar column? Either you need to support Unicode data (in which case your destination columns should be nvarchar) or you need to be ok with Unicode characters from the source being lost.

Comment: I am OK with Unicode characters being lost, What I cant understand is why I can see the correct data in the view but when moved to my table it adds the "?", over all the product SKUs I have encountered (100,000's of thousands, none have the question mark in the data as I can see it is not there when typed and I have made sure it is not data being pasted directly into SAP as a new product. I don't understand why it is getting added after the data conversion) also why this seems to be happening now and has not happened over the last year or so. Will add further comment.

Comment: Sap when hosted locally used VARCHAR mainly in its tables but once moved to the cloud the DB was changed to NVARCHAR, so that is why my old tables are still VARCHAR, I can change but it is strange that it is these few strings that have the problem. especially as they are typed as is and not pasted from an email or a pdf.

Comment: Impossible for us to know, you'll need to intercept a bad value as it's coming across and either store it as Unicode somewhere temporary or inspect its binary value.

Comment: I am unsure how to inspect binary data but can create a script to redirect the data to a table with the same nvarchar structure rather than converting it, is this what you are suggesting ?

Comment: Yes and tell SSIS _not_ to do any codepage conversion.

Comment: Thankyou @AaronBertrand, I will take what you have said and give this a try.  I will be able to do some quick testing to see if what you have suggested has an effect on my data as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why this is happening?

As you mentioned you are importing data from a Unicode column (nvarchar) to a non-Unicode column (varchar). The `?` is added since there is a Unicode character that cannot be converted to the *1252 ANSI - Latin I* code page.

#### What is the Unicode character?

To check for this character, temporarily add a derived column with the following expression:

```
CODEPOINT([column]
```

The [CODEPOINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/codepoint-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) function is used to:

> Returns the Unicode code point of the leftmost character of a character expression.

Then, [add a data viewer to check the values generated](http://binaryworld.net/blogs/use-ssis-data-viewer-dataflow-task/).

Once you know the Unicode value, you can check it from the [Unicode Table](https://unicode-table.com/en/)

#### How to remove it?

To remove this character from the beginning of the string value, you can use the following derived column expression *(assuming that the Unicode character code is 10)*:

```
CODEPOINT([column]) == 10 ? SUBSTRING([column],2,LEN([column]) - 1) : [column]
```

Answer (score 0):

It means some unprintable character is coming in the original `product_sku`, which is not able to converted to `VARCHAR` datatype. I would suggest you to do the below, as part of the data pull.

**SQL SERVER 2017+**

```
TRIM(product_sku)
```

**Earlier versions of SQL SERVER 2017**

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(product_sku))
```

Comment: my code as I posted gets rid of the unwanted character I just wanted to know why it was appearing now and not before.

Comment: update AllQuotes_Table set product_sku = RIGHT(product_sku,LEN(product_sku)-1) WHERE product_sku LIKE '?%';

Comment: @JohnSpencer, may be the new characters are appearing now in the product_sku. you need to check with source system, how this data is coming

Comment: This I have checked, I normally pull new Product data via CSV's or API's but this data I have been having trouble with I have inputted manually( to make sure no strange characters other than what I am typing are submitted). so when pulled into my sqlDB I find strange I can see fine is I query a view but do not understand why it appears when I move the data to a table, that the "?" is appearing